# Internal Server Error after Facebook Login Facebook PHP SDK 4.0.17

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I've got a problem. My code worked perfectly few days ago. But now it does not. I've changed nothing. Just updated SDK version from 4.0.0 to 4.0.17. Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

require_once( 'Foursquare/FoursquareAPI.class.php');

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

$facebookAppKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$facebookSecretKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $facebookAppKey, $facebookSecretKey);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("http://fb.goodnia.com/");


if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

    try {
        if ( !$session->validate() ) {
            $session = null;
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $session = null;
    }
}

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {

    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
        print_r( $ex );
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
        print_r( $ex );
    }

}

if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
    $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    $email = $graphObject->getProperty('email');
    $userlink = $graphObject->getProperty('link');
    $name = $graphObject->getProperty('name');
    $gender = $graphObject->getProperty('gender');
    $identifier = $graphObject->getProperty('id');

    print_r($email);
    }
?>
```

Here's the link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl(array( 'email', 'user_friends','publish_actions' ));?>" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg loginWithFacebook"></a>
```

So when i click the link, it redirects me to Facebook authorization page. After inserting my credentials, it redirects me back. But with such params as "code" and "state".

Here it is:
Request URL:  http://fb.goodnia.com/?code=AQDe3te_RigftBZoM3GqSto3-SO7d8hMoSGeCFj5i-Js_vB1_X9rb_3N4UoWVSAacY_jbHQf_78E4djrZkYRBxcUvi6cHI8xuH_bknit-f9Fmn5F7s8gaT8Z3i2bKeY-6nGOyRryMVKLqlhGhrDbmp9AshuzmljKOAi06_nC_Ygv2wtwcDEqAbn4dP_8QxCnHitK7tdd0qxhCYVe1LTO_PQrky8lABn2koeLcK5n8l5TS65-obVqJTRI-z_UgZ8feSnOZv3a1fSa2yXocCNHBh5f4lrmrBKnxmf6N47kTXIen4ARmbYNfvmdtlN6ec84mBMz-EZAQUcAWaLuC54zusjz&state=c95ad1b3df3f4044c203029a9b6cac03
Request Method:GET
Status Code:  500 Internal Server Error

Where am I wrong? I appreciate your help.